# Browser's back button doesn't work when reloadOnSearch is false in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, back

Browser's back button doesn't work when reloadOnSearch is false.
I used routeUpdate event to update browser's history but it didn't work.

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function() {
window.history.pushState($location.$$url);
});
```

How to enable the back button?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having the same issue, reloadOnSearch is false and none of the route update events fire on pressing the back button